# python can draw figure like this?Which package or function should be used?

Tags: python, visualization

If python can visualizate data matrixs like this? I search for it, but just find in R. I want to know whether python can do this. And which package or function should be used?
[image: visualization of data matrixs]

Comment: This is mtcars dataset, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at matplotlib's gallery:

http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Especially:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo2.html

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful.